# Do inheritance right

Tags: c#, inheritance, business-objects

I have class:

```
internal class Stage
{
    public long StageId { get; set; }
    public string StageName { get; set; }
    public int? Order { get; set; }

    public Stage()
    {
        Order = 0;
    }
}
```

I have also:

```
public class GroupStage : Stage
{
    private override long StageId { set { StageId = value; } }

    public GroupStage() : base() { }

    public void InsertStage(long groupId)
    {
    }

    public static void SetStageOrder(long stageId, int order)
    {
     ....
    }

    public static void DeleteStage(long stageId)
    {
     ....
    }

    public static GroupStage[] GetStages(long groupId)
    {
     ....
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class TaskStage : Stage
{
    public DateTime? Time { get; set; }

    public TaskStage()
        : base()
    {
     ....
    }

    public static Stage GetNextTaskStage(Guid companyId, long taskId)
    {
     ....
    }

    public static Stage[] GetTaskStages(Guid companyId, long taskId)
    {
     ....
    }
}
```

This is not working and I get the exception:
Inconsistent accessibility: base class `Stage` is less accessible than class `GroupStage`

I want `Stage` class to be private and without access except to `GroupStage` and `TaskStage`. I also want to make `StageId` be private in `GroupStage` and in `TaskStage`.
How can I do that without duplicate the members of `Stage` in `GroupStage` and in `TaskStage`?

Comment: "Do inheritance right" .. Ok, so where's your **behavior**?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: You are asking how to do inheritance right, but your classes have no behavior (other than some static CRUD/ActiveRecord). If you want to "do inheritance right" your design would center around behavior in your classes, not bags of properties. In other words, I'm saying you're doing it wrong.  Very wrong.

Comment: It seems like you are using inheritance simply for the sake of using inheritance.  When I see that your base class contains nothing more than basic properties, it's a serious code stink. There's no point to inheritance in the example you use. Then there's all the static methods .. another code smell. And you seem to be placing far too much concern on accessibility levels. I don't mean to be disparaging, because it seems like you are somewhat new to OO, but you appear to making some fairly grievous errors in design.

Comment: How come you can make a property less accessible in a derived class (StageId)? Anyone care to explain? Would appreciate it.

Comment: @Dave O.: You wouldn't. Trying to would be a mistake on several levels. It is one of many glaring problems in the OP's code.

Comment: @qes: What do you meen by "behavior"? how do you suggest to implement this?

Comment: @Naor: Well, your `Stage` class has properties: StageId, StageName, Order, etc.. Somewhere, you will have code that reads and modifies those properties. But what you should likely be striving for is to move that code into your classes. A class should contain data and behavior. In most cases, the main way you should interact with your class is by calling methods on it. Organizationally, the code should be with the data it acts on, and as much as feasible that data should be contained in the class and not shared, especially not for modification (setters).

Comment: There is also nothing shared between your base class and your derived classes (except a few properties). This strongly indicates you do not need a base class or inheritance to solve any issues here. And even if you had an issue to solve, inheritance is often not the best solution. A good rule of thumb is to favor composition.

Comment: @qes: But TaskStage and GroupStage are also Stage. Maybe tomorrow I'll add methods to Stage which will apply on TaskStage and GroupStage.

Answer (score 4):

You can't make a derived class more accessible than it's base class. What you can do is make TaskStage and GroupStage internal as well, then inherit and expose public interfaces so that only the interface is visible outside of your assembly.

```
public interface IGroupStage
{
    public string StageName{ get; set; }
    ...
}

interal class GroupStage : IGroupStage
{
...
}
```

Comment: In this solution I end up with 5 files. How can I arrange them in my library? which files will be under which folder? this method is very complex in terms of files quantity.

Comment: Correct OOP will often lead to an increased amount of files.

Comment: 5 files is nothing in the real world. It took me a while to get over my fear of many files, then I realized there's no reason to have that fear. Just use folders. In this case, I'd put all 5 files in the same folder though. Maybe a "Stages" folder. Visual Studio will automatically put them in a sub-namespace too, which I like.

Comment: @Paul Alexander: Can you explain more how to do it and refer to the folders and names I should give to each file/class?

Comment: @Naor: Remember source code is for the _developer_. So arrange the sources in whatever layout makes sense to you. If it makes sense to you to organize the files into a separate folder do that. Visual Studio doesn't really care. Personally I'd probably stick the interface and class definition in the same file just so it's easier to add methods/properties to both as I develop.

Comment: @Paul Alexander: Can you give refrences to this design pattern?

Comment: @Naor: I can't site any formal documentation, just sharing my own experience solving these types of problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make you Stage class public or protected. if you make it abstract it cant be instantiated on that level, so if its public you dont have to worry about it being created as a base class

Answer (score 1):

Make it `protected` instead of private. If you make it protected, you let classes that inherit from it call methods on the base class, and inherit the base class members.

Comment: And then I get: Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as private, protected, or protected.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably actually want is for Stage to be an abstract base class which, therefore, cannot directly be instantiated regardless of its accessibility modifier.  Change your definition of Stage:

```
public abstract class Stage
{
    protected long StageId { get; set; }
    public string StageName { get; set; }
    public int? Order { get; set; }

    protected Stage()
    {
        Order = 0;
    }
}
```

The protected modifier means that your derived classes will be able to access that member, but it will not be accessible outside those classes.